# How to use multiple root route in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

Just updated to rails 6 and having trouble with a conditional root route

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated  do
      root to: 'users#show'
    end
    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'visitors#index'
    end
  end
```

I've attempted to check for the logged-in user in visitors#index and do a redirect to users#show but now I have this ugly URL '/users/:id' instead of being able to visit users#show with a clean root URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to solve this by adding an `:as` argument:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'users#show'
    end
    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'visitors#index', as: :visitors_url
    end
  end
```

I think the reasoning behind the change is to make it so that Rails knows where to route `root_url`.

Note: I found the [answer on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/eeifx1/defining_root_twice_inside_routesrb_doesnt_work/) where it was suggested using `namespace` would be cleaner.

```
namespace :visitors, path: nil do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
end
```

I don't know if there is a way to make that work with devise though.